Problem with using NewType for parameters validation with FastAPI
I was wondering if there is a workaround to this problem. I want to use NewType to define and validate query parameters like this:
DefaultQueryType = NewType("DefaultQueryType", Annotated[list[str], Query()])


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: DefaultQueryType):
    query_items = {"q": q}
    return query_items

but I get error

422 Error: Unprocessable Entity` - Input should be a valid list

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem, so defined new type can be used in multiple places without writing it as function parameter every time?
I checked FastAPI github but it seems to be still an issue https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/discussions/8214#discussioncomment-5148270.

You shouldn't need to use NewType. Just doing
DefaultQueryType = Annotated[list[str], Query()]

should work.
